# How to align RGB and Depth image from Kinect in Matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect

I am trying to align RGB and Depth image from Kinect using Matlab. I am trying to do it using the algorithm from [this](http://burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration#tocLink5) page.

Here is the code I have written so far

```
depth = imread('depth_00500.png');
color = imread('rgb_00500.png');

rotationMat=[9.9984628826577793e-01 1.2635359098409581e-03 -1.7487233004436643e-02;
 -1.4779096108364480e-03 9.9992385683542895e-01 -1.2251380107679535e-02;
1.7470421412464927e-02 1.2275341476520762e-02 9.9977202419716948e-01 ];

 translationMat=[1.9985242312092553e-02, -7.4423738761617583e-04, -1.0916736334336222e-02 ];

%parameters for color matrix
fx_rgb= 5.2921508098293293e+02;
fy_rgb= 5.2556393630057437e+02;
cx_rgb= 3.2894272028759258e+02;
cy_rgb= 2.6748068171871557e+02;
k1_rgb= 2.6451622333009589e-01;
k2_rgb= -8.3990749424620825e-01;
p1_rgb= -1.9922302173693159e-03;
p2_rgb= 1.4371995932897616e-03;
k3_rgb= 9.1192465078713847e-01;

%parameters for depth matrix
fx_d= 5.9421434211923247e+02;
fy_d= 5.9104053696870778e+02;
cx_d= 3.3930780975300314e+02;
cy_d= 2.4273913761751615e+02;
k1_d= -2.6386489753128833e-01;
k2_d =9.9966832163729757e-01;
p1_d =-7.6275862143610667e-04;
p2_d =5.0350940090814270e-03;
k3_d =-1.3053628089976321e+00;

row_num=480;
col_num=640;

for row=1:row_num
    for col=1:col_num

pixel3D(row,col,1) = (row - cx_d) * depth(row,col) / fx_d;
pixel3D(row,col,2) = (col - cy_d) * depth(row,col) / fy_d;
pixel3D(row,col,3) = depth(row,col);

    end
end

pixel3D(:,:,1)=rotationMat*pixel3D(:,:,1)+translationMat;
pixel3D(:,:,2)=rotationMat*pixel3D(:,:,2)+translationMat;
pixel3D(:,:,3)=rotationMat*pixel3D(:,:,3)+translationMat;

P2Drgb_x = fx_rgb*pixel3D(:,:,1)/pixel3D(:,:,3)+cx_rgb;
P2Drgb_y = fy_rgb*pixel3D(:,:,2)/pixel3D(:,:,3)+cy_rgb;
```

I am especially failing to understand why we're assigning value of depth pixel to dimension x,y and z of 3-dimensional space, shouldn't we assign (x,y,z) dimension to the depth pixel value?

I mean this part:

```
P3D.x = (x_d - cx_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fx_d
P3D.y = (y_d - cy_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fy_d
P3D.z = depth(x_d,y_d)
```

Also I'm not sure If I can represent 3d space using matrix. I am trying to use it in my code but for sure it has wrong size as multiplication by 3x3 rotation matrix is impossible.

Thank you for very much for every suggestion and help!

Answer (score 3):

This is a quite complex topic to explain in a short answer. As per me, the code is correct. Please read about intrinsic and extrinsic camera matrices. And reading about perspective projection will also help you to understand 2D to 3D projection.

```
P3D.x = (x_d - cx_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fx_d
```

In above line, `depth(x_d, y_d)` gives you the depth value at a pixel from the depth image. Then it is multiplied by the `(x_d - cx_d)`, which is the difference along x-axis with the x coordinate of the centre point of depth map to the current pixel. Then finally this is divided by the `fx_d`, which is the focal length of the depth camera.

Following two references will help you to understand this mathematically well if you are interested in.

1. [Mueller, K., Smolic, A., Dix, K., Merkle, P., Kauff, P., & Wiegand, T. (2008). View synthesis for advanced 3D video systems. EURASIP Journal on Image and Video Processing, 2008(1), 1-11](http://www.ic.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg121/publications/2008_5_View_Synthesis_for_Advanced_3D_Video_Systems.pdf).
2. [Daribo, I., & Saito, H. (2011). A novel inpainting-based layered depth video for 3DTV. Broadcasting, IEEE Transactions on, 57(2), 533-541](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5743033&tag=1).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Nevertheless, my problem is not understanding the right side of the equation, but the left one. I fail to understand what we're actually calculating. Does 'P3D.x' give us coordinate x in 3d system of pixel from 2d with coordinates (x_d, y_d)? So does it mean that we have pixel in 2d of coordinates (x_d,y_d) and these formulas let us calculate coordinates of point in 3d system, with coordinates ( P3D.x, P3D.y, P3D.z)? And then we are assigning value of depth(x_d,y_d) in ( P3D.x, P3D.y, P3D.z) point in space?

Comment: Yes, P3D here represents the 3D world coordinates x, y, and z. So we project 2D image coordinates (x_d, y_d) to the world (x, y) coordinates using the P3D.x and P3D.y coordinates. Then for the z, value from the depth camera has been assigned.