# How to get depth value of specific RGB pixels in Kinect v2 images using Matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping, kinect

I'm working with the Kinect v2 and I have to map the depth information onto the RGB images to process them: in particular, I need to know which pixels in the RGB images are in a certain range of distance (depth) along the Z axis; I'm acquiring all the data with a C# program and saving them as images (RGB) and txt files (depth).

I've followed the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003005/how-to-align-rgb-and-depth-image-from-kinect-in-matlab) and [here](http://burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration) (and I thank them for sharing), but I still have some problems I don't know how to solve.

I have calculated the rotation (R) and translation (T) matrix between the depth sensor and the RGB camera, as well as their intrinsic parameters.

I have created P3D_d (depth pixels in world coordinates related to depth sensor) and P3D_rgb (depth pixels in world coordinates related to rgb camera).

```
row_num = 424;
col_num = 512;

P3D_d = zeros(row_num,col_num,3);
P3D_rgb = zeros(row_num,col_num,3);
cont = 1;
for row=1:row_num
    for col=1:col_num
        P3D_d(row,col,1) = (row - cx_d) * depth(row,col) / fx_d;
        P3D_d(row,col,2) = (col - cy_d) * depth(row,col) / fy_d;
        P3D_d(row,col,3) = depth(row,col);

        temp = [P3D_d(row,col,1);P3D_d(row,col,2);P3D_d(row,col,3)];

        P3D_rgb(row,col,:) = R*temp+T;
    end
end
```

I have created P2D_rgb_x and P2D_rgb_y.

```
P2D_rgb_x(:,:,1) = (P3D_rgb(:,:,1)./P3D_rgb(:,:,3))*fx_rgb+cx_rgb;
P2D_rgb_y(:,:,2) = (P3D_rgb(:,:,2)./P3D_rgb(:,:,3))*fy_rgb+cy_rgb;
```

but now I don't understand how to continue.

Assuming that the calibration parameters are correct, I've tried to click on a defined point in both the depth (coordinates: row_d, col_d) and rgb (coordinates: row_rgb, col_rgb) images, but P2D_rgb_x(row_d, col_d) is totally different from row_rgb, as well as P2D_rgb_y(row_d, col_d) is totally different from col_rgb.

So, what do exactly mean P2D_rgb_x and P2D_rgb_y? How can I use them to map depth value onto rgb images or just to get the depth of a certain RGB pixel?

I'll apreciate any suggest or help!

PS: I've also a related post on MathWorks at this link

Comment: I've never used kinect with matlab. But, just to make sure, Size of depth frame and rgb frame is different. Depth frame is of size 512*424, while color frame size is 1920*1080. I've mention this because both your `P3D_d` and `P3D_rgb` are of the same size 512*424.